# datetime.date: TypeError: an integer is required. Why?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

```
class Photo:
    'Fields: size, pdate'
    def __init__(self, size, pdate):
        self.size = size
        self.pdate = pdate

def create_photo_name_dict(pdel):
    photo_dictionary = {}
    for photo in pdel:
        photo_dictionary[photo[0]] = Photo(photo[1],datetime.date(photo[2:]).isoformat())
    return photo_dictionary

create_photo_name_dict([["DSC315.JPG",55,2011,11,13],["DSC316.JPG",53,2011,11,12]])
```

This produces  `TypeError: an integer is required`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

`datetime.date` needs an integer as its parameters. With `photo[2:]` You are passing a slice, which is a list. Hence the error.

To solve this, unpack the list:

```
photo_dictionary[photo[0]] = Photo(photo[1],datetime.date(*photo[2:]).isoformat())
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> datetime.date([2010,8, 7])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#71>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.date([2010,8, 7])
TypeError: an integer is required
>>> datetime.date(*[2010,8, 7])
datetime.date(2010, 8, 7)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
photo_dictionary[photo[0]] = Photo(photo[1],datetime.date(photo[2:]).isoformat())
```

Here, you are getting string in `photo[0]`.. you need to typecast it using  `int(photo[0])`.

Also Check whether you are getting `photo[0]` `int` in `string` format

```
photo_dictionary[int(photo[0])] = Photo(photo[1],datetime.date(photo[2:]).isoformat())
```